# React Native (Expo) OneSignal InApp Messagt trigger

Tags: react-native, expo, onesignal

i want to show (and set) in my Settings screen the state of Notification Permission. For Notifications i use OneSignal (which is already working). But i'm struggling with show the current Notification Permission and trigger an "In-App Message"

In OneSignal i added an "In-App Trigger" - setPermission is 1
but if i trigger this from the app the In-App Message was not displayed (If i change from trigger to "On app open" it worked).

Also the OneSignal.Notifications.hasPermission(); does not return the current Notficiation Permission...

I'm using
"react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.2"

Hopefully someone give me a hint...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { OneSignal } from 'react-native-onesignal';
import ConfigApp from '../config/ConfigApp';
import { View, ScrollView, I18nManager } from 'react-native';
import { RadioButton, Switch, Paragraph, List, Divider } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function Settings(props) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check the push notification permission
    const checkNotificationPermission = async () => {
      OneSignal.initialize(ConfigApp.ONESIGNAL_APP_ID); 
      //const deviceState = await OneSignal.getDeviceState();
      const deviceState = OneSignal.Notifications.hasPermission();
      if (!deviceState) {
        //const areNotificationsEnabled = deviceState.areNotificationsEnabled;
        //setNotificationPermission(areNotificationsEnabled);
      }
    };

    checkNotificationPermission();
  }, []);

  // Function to request notification permission
  const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
    OneSignal.InAppMessages.addTrigger("setPermission", "1");
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
     
      <View>
        

        <View>
          <Paragraph>{Strings.ST327}</Paragraph>
          <Switch value={soundSetting === true} onValueChange={toggleSoundSetting} />
        </View>

       
        
        <View>
          <Paragraph>{Strings.ST329}</Paragraph>
          <Switch value={notificationPermission} onValueChange={requestNotificationPermission} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```